# Multer file upload error (nodejs and react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer

I've sent this request from client.

```
if(file){
      const data = new FormData()
      const fileName = Date.now() + file.name
      data.append('file', file) // file comes from state while submitting
      data.append('name', fileName)
      try {
        await axios.post('/upload_image', data)      
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
}
```

Nodejs

```
const multer = require('multer')


// file upload
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    cb(null, "./public/images/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name)
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
router.post("/upload_image", upload.single('file'), (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
    try {
        res.status(200).json("file uploaded successfully")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

If I print req.body in

```
router.post("/upload_image", upload.single('file'), (req,res)=>{
 console.log(req.body.name)
console.log(req.file)
......................
.......................
})
```

Here name gets printed and `req.file` also gets printed. But, inside

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    ...................
..............................
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(req.body.name); //undefined  
    cb(null, req.body.name)
  },
});
```

name becomes undefined and app gets crashed. Why the req object didn't go to `diskStorage` function. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [multer documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage):

> Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

If you append the name *before* the file in the frontend, the name should be available at `req.body.name`.

```js
// Append name first before we send the file
// so we can access it in the backend
data.append('name', fileName);
data.append('file', file);
```

Alternatively, you can send the file name directly with the file as the 3rd argument to the append function:

```js
data.append('file', file, fileName);
```

You can then access the file name in the backend with `req.file.originalname`. Consult this free [Request Parsing in Node.js Guide](https://maximorlov.com/request-parsing-nodejs-guide/) whenever you're working with file uploads in Node.js.